# DBSCAN Clustering with Numerical and Categorical Variables

Tags: rstudio, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I just wanted to ask how to deal with Categorical variables in Clustering using DBSCAN? And what methods to be used to deal with them?

Answer (score -1):

DBSCAN is based on Euclidian distances (epsilon neighborhoods). You need to transform your data so Euclidean distance makes sense. One way to do this would be to use 0-1 dummy variables, but it depends on the application.

Comment: DBSCAN never was limited to Euclidean distances. They also used distances between polygons, for example. Literally *any* distance can be used. In fact (see GDBSCAN) you do not even need any of the distance axioms, a binary predicate is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is true, but since finding neighbors is efficient in low-dimensions for the  l1 and l2 norm, most implementations will only provide these or a complete distance matrix which only works for very small data sets.

Comment: There are well-known tools that support other distances, such as ELKI and sklearn. Also inverted indexes work well with categorical variables. And in particular, the user **asked for categorical variables**, so the answer then probably should be rather "choose a tool that allows you to specify arbitrary distances; if you can affort to do so, just compute a distance matrix." Typical indexes for Euclidean distance (e.g., k-d-tree) will *not* work on 0-1 encoded data. Right now, your answer misses the question, doesn't it?